# Handling database transaction returns

Tags: javascript, database, transactions, return

Here I have a function that is supposed to return the number of seconds as the variable sec but the return statement is running before the database transaction so I keep getting undefined. What can I do to make sure the transaction finishes before the return calls. Similar to `onreadystatechange` for `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
function getLevelSeconds (index) {
    var sec;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SPLevelData', [], function (tx, result) {sec=result.rows.item(index).seconds;}, errorCB)}, errorCB);
    return sec;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Implement callback

```
function getLevelSeconds (index, callback) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SPLevelData', [], function (tx, result) {
            sec=result.rows.item(index).seconds;
            typeof callback == "function" && callback(sec);
        }, errorCB);
    }, errorCB);
}

getLevelSeconds(index, function(sec) {
    alert(sec);
});
```

For detailed info refer to [JavaScript: 4 asyncronys functions to wait for each other sequentially to finish before continuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269703/javascript-4-asyncronys-functions-to-wait-for-each-other-sequentially-to-finish/25269955#25269955) answer.